# Log4j2 doesn't log into logfile

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, web-applications, log4j2

I changed the path of log4j2.xml configuration file and now the log files will create but application doesn't log into the files. I get no error messages.

My order structur:
[image: order structur]

**Log4j2.xml**:

```
<Properties>
    <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
        %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5level ${hostName} --- [%15.15thread] %-100.100class : %message%n%exception
    </Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
    <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
    </Console>

    <RollingFile name="RootAppender" fileName="./log/log.log" filePattern="./log/log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100MB" />
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="7"/>
    </RollingFile>

    <RollingFile name="CurlAppender" fileName="./log/curl.log" filePattern="./log/curl-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500MB" />
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="7"/>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        <AppenderRef ref="RootAppender"/>
    </Root>

    <Logger name="CurlLogger" level="trace" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="CurlAppender"/>
    </Logger>
</Loggers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the issue.
In the application.properties file there must be set the "logger.config" attribute.
After setting this attribute, the file logging works.

Comment: Can you pls give some details about this `logger.config` property? It seems I may have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some issue in Loggers tag.
In the Logger name please add your package name and also change your AppenderRef in Logger.

Please change your xml code to below:

```
<Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        <AppenderRef ref="RootAppender"/>
    </Root>

    <Logger name="com.example.springbackend.controller" level="trace" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        <AppenderRef ref="RootAppender"/>
    </Logger>
</Loggers>
```

Here `<Logger name="com.example.springbackend.controller" level="trace" additivity="false">` Logger name is project package name.

Comment: I have check the logger name and changed, them to the package name. But nothing changed...

Comment: Please add <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" /> inside the Logger tag.

Comment: The console logger is working but the rollingfile logger is not working. The java application creates the logfile but doesn't write anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in root level.
Please change the root level logger to debug or trace.

Comment: I have changed the root loglevel to debug, but nothing changed. I have also changed them to trace. If a switch the log4j2.xml to the src/main/resources folder, then i can log everything. But when the xml-file is in /conf folder, then nothing is logged. Only the default files will generate.

Comment: Then the issue in location.

Comment: Yes i know, but i can't find the issue. I have change anything, but nothing changed. The application doesn't log into the logfile.